# Creating Azure File Storage SAS in Salesforce does not work

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-storage, apex

I am trying to create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the Azure File Storage in Salesforce Apex but not getting anywhere. Here is my code:

```
String link = 'https://<accountName>.file.core.windows.net/<folderName>/test.txt';
String key = '...' // key of the account

String spe = 'r'; //read
String st = '2018-06-07T08:49:00Z';
String se = '2018-06-09T08:49:00Z';
String res = '/file/<accountName>/<folderName>/test.txt';
String sv = '2017-11-09';
String sr = 'f'; // file
String spr = 'https';

String sts = spe + '\n'  +
    st + '\n' +
    se + '\n' +
    res + '\n' +
    spr + '\n'+
    sv + '\n';  

Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(sts), Blob.valueOf(key));
String sas = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
sas = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(sas, 'UTF-8');
link += '?sv=' + sv + '&st=' + st + '&se=' + se + '&sr=' + sr + '&sp=' + spe 
               + '&spr=' + spr + '&sig=' + sas;
System.debug(link);
```

When I copy paste the link in the browser, the response is:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>
    Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:... Time:2018-06-07T21:56:01.7374549Z
  </Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
    Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2018-06-07T08:49:00Z 2018-06-09T08:49:00Z /file/<accountName>/<folderName>/test.txt https 2017-11-09
  </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Blob.valueof(key) will take the utf-8 data from the string, this is unlikely to be format your key is actually in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @superfell in the comments, the issue is with the following line of code:

```
Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(sts), Blob.valueOf(key));
```

Please change this line of code to:

```
Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(sts), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key));
```

and you should not get this error. Essentially the key is a base64 encoded string and you need to use proper decoding method to get a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the error message, this seems to be related to an authentication issue, I'd recommend visiting this two links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas

and https://zimmergren.net/azure-storage-rest-api-authenticate-with-c/ to check the validity of your auth header:

```
an example of an account SAS:

https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/sample-container?restype=container&comp=metadata&sv=2015-04-05ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2015-09-20T08:49Z&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&sig=a39%2BYozJhGp6miujGymjRpN8tsrQfLo9Z3i8IRyIpnQ%3d
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gaurav. Your solution worked, however, it was incomplete. It was still giving me the error. Here is what I did to make it work:

```
String spe = 'r';
String st = '';
String se = '2018-06-10T07:00:00Z';
String res = '/file/<accountName>/<folderName>/test.txt';
String si = '';
String sip = '';
String spr = '';
String sr = 'f';
String sv = '2017-11-09';
String rscc = '';
String rscd = '';
String rsce = '';
String rscl = '';
String rsct = '';

String sts = spe + '\n'  +
    st + '\n' +
    se + '\n' +
    res + '\n' +
    si + '\n' +
    sip + '\n' +
    spr + '\n'+
    sv + '\n' +
    rscc + '\n' +
    rscd + '\n' +
    rsce + '\n' +
    rscl + '\n' +
    rsct;

Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(sts), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key));
String sas = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
sas = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(sas, 'UTF-8');
link += '?sv=' + sv + '&se=' + se + '&sr=' + sr + '&sp=' + spe + '&sig=' + sas;
System.debug(link);
```